# How to properly validate a svg string in C#?

Tags: c#, svg

I'm trying to verify that a given string is valid svg using this little util method I made:

```
public static bool IsValidSvg(string str) {
    try {
        var svg = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(str));
        return svg.Root.Name.LocalName.Equals("svg");
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works for 90% of the cases, but, for instance, I have an svg which has an opening tag as follows:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
 x="0px" y="0px" width="599.33398px" height="490.66748px" viewBox="0 0 599.33398 490.66748"
 enable-background="new 0 0 599.33398 490.66748" xml:space="preserve">
```

Then the validation fails because it doesn't know what ns_extend is... It throws:

> System.Xml.XmlException: Referenced entity 'ns_extend' does not exist.  Line 1, position 53.

How can I get around this? The svg renders properly, so it should be a valid svg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty fix for your method:

```
private static bool IsSvg(string input)
{
    try
    {
        using (var file = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(file) {XmlResolver = null})
            return reader.Read() && reader.Name.Equals("svg", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

By setting the `XmlResolver` property to `null` the reader will ignore DTD reference.

Comment: This doesn't work when the svg file has an xml declaration <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>